# Purpose of PEAR in PHP

Tags: php

I have just started with PHP development since last week. I have installed XAMPP on my PC. I just want to know few questions that are:

1. What is the purpose of PEAR folder that is inside the PHP folder?
2. How can I implement polymorphism in PHP?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEAR

Comment: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/about.pear.php :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [faq](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A PEAR package is distributed as a gzipped tar file. Each archive
>   consists of source code written in PHP, usually in an object-oriented
>   style. Many PEAR packages can readily be used by developers as
>   ordinary third party code via simple include statements in PHP. More
>   elegantly, the PEAR package manager which comes with PHP by default
>   may be used to install PEAR packages so that the extra functionality
>   provided by the package appears as an integrated part of the PHP
>   installation. Unlike the Comprehensive Perl Archive Network (CPAN)
>   archives, which PEAR took as its model, PEAR packages do not have
>   implicit dependencies so that a package's placement in the PEAR
>   package tree does not relate to code dependencies. Rather, PEAR
>   packages must explicitly declare all dependencies on other PEAR
>   packages.
>
> The PEAR base classes contain code for simulating object-oriented
>   destructors and consistent error-handling. Packages exist for many
>   basic PHP functions including authentication, caching, database
>   access, encryption, configuration, HTML, web services and XML.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEAR

Answer (score 1):

To implement Polymorphism in PHP, you can use interfaces and abstract classes.

```
interface Shape{
   public function getArea();
}

class Circle implements Shape{
 ... 
}

abstract class Polygon implements Shape{
   ...
}

class Square extends Polygon{
  ...
}
```

As a matter of fact, type checking in PHP is not strict. And you don't need to declare a type for your variable. Then invoking any function on any object is possible (although very error prone and not elegant). In the previous example, you could invoke the "getArea" on any "Square" or "Circle" instances even if the classes does not implement the Shape interface.

Edit:
As of PHP 5.4, you can also use [traits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) for polymorphism.